# Moving a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to know how to move a div(box2) to go all the way to the right of the screen and disappear when the user hovers over another div(box1). I know we have to use Jquery. As of now I know how to make the box2 disappear by using the toggle function but Im not really sure how to use the animate function to move it to the right and then disappear. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you don't have to use jQuery for anything.

Comment: How about making a jsfiddle out of what you have already?

Answer (score 2):

One way of sliding an element across the screen, and then fading it out:

```
    // get the widths of the window (or the parent of the element to move):
var winWidth = $(window).width(),

    // get the width of the element itself:
    demoWidth = $('#demo').width(),

    // find out how far to move the element:
    delta = winWidth - demoWidth,

    // the time-frame over which to animate:
    duration = 1500;

// bind the animate method:    
$('#demo').animate({
    // move the element the distance held by the 'delta' variable:
    'left': delta
// animate for the duration defined by 'duration':
}, duration,

// callback function, to occur once first stage of the animation has completed:    
function () {
    // binding the fadeOut() method:
    $(this).fadeOut(duration);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNaFC/).

The above demo uses the (simple) HTML:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#demo {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: #f00;
    /* to move an element, using the 'left' property,
       the 'position' must be set to a value other than 'static' (the default):
    */
    position: relative;
}
```

To do the same, once the `#box1` element is hovered-over:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width(),
    demoWidth = $('#box2').width(),
    delta = winWidth - demoWidth,
    duration = 1500;

$('#box1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#box2').animate({
        'left': delta
    }, duration,

    function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(duration);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNaFC/2).

The above using the following HTML:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to use $.animate()?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Basically...

```
$(document).ready()
{
    $(selector).animate(
        {
            "backgroundColor" : "red"
        }, 500, "swing");
}
```

Plug in your selector, you should know how to do that.

Animate has two main arguments, but I've added a third, which is "easing".

The first is an object literal containing changes to CSS.

The second is time in milliseconds for the animation to complete.

The third is easing, which allows you to animate on a curve. Default is "linear", which looks stiff.

Your question doesn't really seem to exist. If you are just asking for general information, try looking it up in a search engine first.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but you could consider using hover() and animate() on hover.

```
<div class='slide-right'>howdy</div>
<div class='slide-right'>doody</div>
```

It's entirely up to you which attributes you use to do the sliding right. Here I've animated the left margin as an example. This will have layout implications so consider using `left` and absolute positioning instead. You can optionally animate the opacity as it slides in and out of view.

```
$('.slide-right').hover(function() 
                        { 
                          $(this).siblings('.slide-right').animate({ 'margin-left': '+=50' }); 
                        },    
                        function() 
                        { 
                          $(this).siblings('.slide-right').animate({ 'margin-left': '-=50' }); 
                        });
```